# NSXMLDocumentTidyXML and preserving whitespace

Tags: cocoa, nsxmldocument

I'm using NSXMLDocument to parse some XML. It's XML that comes in from a web service, and it's often malformed so I need to pass `NSXMLDocumentTidyXML` to be able to parse it.

However, I'd like to preserve line breaks in text, which NSXMLDocumentTidyXML strips out.

I know from the documentation that the `xmlns:space="preserve"` attribute will tell the XML tidier to preserve whitespace. However, since I need that to be in the XML before I begin parsing, and it's only after parsing that I can add attributes to nodes, I'm not sure what to do.

Any suggestions? The only thing I can think of at the moment is manually searching through the string for the root tag, applying the attribute by just inserting it into the input string, then parsing that. That seems pretty fragile to me…

Comment: As it happens, I've sidestepped the issue — the only malformed-ness of my particular files was that there was trailing whitespace, and sometimes they would be completely empty. I've handled those two cases specifically and am no longer using `NSXMLDocumentTidyXML`. 

Leaving this up in case an answer helps someone else.